# how to check if a type of row exists in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Hi I have an order table and a payment table which are linked by order_num.  I would like to get entries from order table who have entries in the payment table of PaymentType 'A' as well as PaymentType 'B' and their amounts match.  Example order number 411 should only be returned to me if it has at least two payments and one of them is paymenttype 'A' and the other one is paymenttype 'b' and amount for both is 45

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your SQL so far?

Comment: What if there are more than one payments of type A or B? Is that possible? Should the total of all A and B payments equal each other or just any pair? Sample data and expected output (covering as many cases as you can think of) would be very helpful is letting us help you.

Comment: there will not be more than 1 payment of Type A and Type B

Comment: I have done an inner join based on whether it's payment Type A or Type b, and it returns me all the results. I'd just like to filter it to results that have both payment types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments state, there is very little info to go off of for a truly definitive answer. Here goes a possible solution, at least in a basic form.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Payment p1 ON o.order_num = p1.order_num
LEFT JOIN Payment p2 ON o.order_num = p2.order_num
WHERE p1.Type = "A"
AND p2.Type = "B"
AND p1.Amount = p2.Amount
```

Comment: perfect.  that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can guarantee that there are at most one A and one B row:

```
SELECT
     <columns here>
FROM
     Orders O
INNER JOIN Payments PA ON
     PA.order_number = O.order_number AND
     PA.payment_type = 'A'
INNER JOIN Payments PB ON
     PB.order_number = O.order_number AND
     PB.payment_type = 'B'
WHERE
     PA.amount = PB.amount
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT      o.OrderID,
            o.Amount
FROM        Order AS o
INNER JOIN  Payment AS pA ON pA.OrderID = o.OrderID AND pA.PaymentType = 'A'
INNER JOIN  Payment AS pB ON pB.OrderID = o.OrderID AND pB.PaymentType = 'B'
WHERE       pA.Amount = pB.Amount
GROUP BY    o.OrderID,
            o.Amount
```

Comment: I believe that the amount is in the Payments table and needs to be equal between the two rows (A & B)

Answer (score 0):

Making some (hopefully) reasonable assumptions about the names of tables, columns, etc, how about...

```
SELECT *
    FROM ORDER_TABLE
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM PAYMENT_TABLE
                      WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE         = 'A'               AND
                            PAYMENT_TABLE.ORDER  = ORDER_TABLE.ORDER AND
                            PAYMENT_TABLE.AMOUNT = ORDER_TABLE.AMOUNT) AND
          EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM PAYMENT_TABLE
                      WHERE PAYMENT_TYPE         = 'B'               AND
                            PAYMENT_TABLE.ORDER  = ORDER_TABLE.ORDER AND
                            PAYMENT_TABLE.AMOUNT = ORDER_TABLE.AMOUNT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes amounts exist only in the payment table, and that the payment table may have multiple records for a payment type.

```
select [columns]
  from ORDER O
 where exists (select null from PAYMENT PA, PAYMENT PB
                where PA.PAYMENT_TYPE = 'A'
                  and PB.PAYMENT_TYPE = 'B'
                  and PA.ORDER_NUM    = O.ORDER_NUM
                  and PB.ORDER_NUM    = O.ORDER_NUM
                  and PA.AMOUNT       = PB.AMOUNT)
```